# Making two maps the same

Tags: qgis, mapping

I am producing radar maps from the NEXRAD site near Omaha (OAX) using GrADS.  I'd like to make a basemap in QGIS.

I put a geotiff version of the GrADS output in QGIS and had it 'zoom to layer.'

In Composer I set the shape parameters to match GrADS 16:9 (in GrADS all lengths are 11", so 11x6.187).

The attached image superimposes my state and city overlay over the states and counties from the radar.  They don't match.[image: overlaid images]

I'd like to make a bunch of basemaps in QGIS... if I can make them comport.  Can someone please help?